# C: for (i=0;i<=N;i++) { t[i] = pow(a,0.i); } ALWAYS returning 1

Tags: c, pow

C programming:
Trying to store in a float table the values of a^i while (a) is an integer variable taken as input and i = 0,N (N also an integer variable taken as input)

Using this function I created:

```
void remplissage(double *t,int a,int N)
{
 int i;
 double aux;

 for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
  {
    t[i] = pow(a,0.i);
  }
}
```

Then displaying the values with:

```
void affichage(double *t,int N)
 {
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<=N;i++)
   {
    printf("tab[%d]= %.3f\n", i, t[i]);
   }
 }
```

Gives me this:

```
Saisir a: 990
Saisir N= 5
tab[0]= 1.000
tab[1]= 1.000
tab[2]= 1.000
tab[3]= 1.000
tab[4]= 1.000
tab[5]= 1.000
```

For whatever (a) and (N) I chose.

Comment: Maybe a typo:  replace pow(a,0.i) by pow(a,i).

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. This contains syntax errors and does not show what the array is, or how it is passed to the function. Also, you probably have an off-by 1 error with `for (i=0;i<=N;i++)`. And what is `double aux;` for?

Comment: Nice try but that's a complex number now, not related to the variable `i`.

Comment: Check the prototype for [\[ pow \]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm) and define your function accordingly

Comment: gcc has a compiler-specific extension that treats `0.i` as an imaginary constant. In standard C, `0.i` is simply a syntax error. Assuming you're using gcc or clang, try compiling with `-pedantic`.

Comment: I'm using cc
But thanks all. It's been figured out :D using i/10.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `0.` in front of `i` (or use `i / 10.0` as second argument to `pow` instead -- see comments).

The way you have it, the exponent is always 0.

Actually, it is not standard compliant code because `i` is an integer suffix and `0.` a float constant. But it seems your compiler accepts it as 0 anyway.

Comment: That's gonna give me
a^0
a^1
a^2
But I need
a^0,0
a^0,1
a^0,2

Comment: That would be `pow(a, i / 10.0)`.

Comment: `0.i` is an *imaginary  constant*, a gcc-specific extension. In standard C it's simply a syntax error.

Comment: @undur_gongor Thanks man; Tried pow(a, i/10) before and it didn't work but with pow(a, i / 10.0) it worked perfectly. But can I ask what difference did the .0 made !

Comment: It makes the 10 a float (double) and hence the division a floating-point division.

Comment: @undur_gongor So 1/10 is not gonna give us 0,1 but 0 right ?

Comment: Right. It is integer division and hence yields truncated results 9/10 -> 0.

Comment: @undur_gongor Thanks